# What is the right way to playing .Swf files on splash screen in android?

Tags: android, flash, android-studio

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Handler;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{


    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String localUrl ="file:///android_asset/flash.swf";

        WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        wv.loadUrl(localUrl);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you facing issues?

Comment: `WebView` cannot load SWF files. The format is not supported natively by Android since 4.1 (if not even earlier). Either use a program like FFmpeg on your computer to convert SWF file to MP4 as video splash, or use Flash CC (now called Flash Animate) to code your app (using AS3 instead of Java). MP4 video file might be best & easiest option for this...